I see rainbow effect on the borders of objects and text, adjusting ClearType or driver reinstall doesn't resolve the issue
I am using a QN90A Samsung TV as my display with an HDMI 2.1 cable. The effect is the most noticeable on Intel integrated graphics (12700K), but also a bit on Nvidia GPU (3070ti).
Image of the error with Intel integrated GPU:


The problem was with YCbCr420 color format. I switched to YCbCr444 or RGB and it went away. I see the best color representation for my display with RGB and full dynamic range (I also set 10 bpc color depth, for the content that can use it).
You can change the setting for Nvidia cards here:


Where do you make that setting?

@ThomasWeller in the Nvidia control panel it is in the resolution tab https://i.sstatic.net/trT1C5ay.jpg (Image borrowed from https://www.tenforums.com/graphic-cards/167180-nvidia-control-panel-output-color-format-changes-itself.html) you may see different settings under there depending on your display, other graphics cards may have the settings in different places.

This is a problem with chroma subsampling where colour data is essentially "compressed" and spread across multiple pixels to reduce bandwidth in a way that, from a distance and depending on content displayed, is less noticeable.
YCbCr444 is "full bandwidth" that is for every pixel it has the same amount of chroma (colour) data as luminance. 422 has half the amount of colour data, and 420 has a quarter.  The result is that for fast moving and changing video that potentially contains large blocks of similar colour that is somewhat dithered then you will not notice much with YCbCr420. You'll only really see it at the edges of text or sharp objects, but chances are they are moving fast enough that the effect will change next frame and be blended away.
With sharp text on a static computer screen you will notice it it exactly the way you have.
By using YCbCr444 you get the "full resolution" of chroma data. Alternatively by selecting RGB you avoid any chroma/luminance artefacts and transmit only "pure" Red/Green/Blue pixel data.
Why would you want YCbCr420 instead of 444?
Because you reduce the amount of bandwidth required for video which allows you to work at higher frame-rates or resolutions for a given amount of bandwidth. To get 4K60 on older HDMI devices it was almost a necessity.
If you have a lot of high-speed motion you might be able to accept an almost indistinguishable loss of colour clarity in return for much faster motion. For sports games it may be entirely acceptable.
For a computer where there is a lot of slow movement and static images that loss of colour fidelity will more often than not be unacceptable so you would need YCbCr444, but you may be stuck at either a lower resolution of 1080p @ 60Hz, or a lower refresh rate of 4K @ 30Hz.
It's all swings and roundabouts.
The problem is knowing that you need to swap between 444 and 420 for particular things to begin with.
With more modern HDMI specs that have far greater bandwidth this problem will decrease, but older TVs and displays may still have this limit.

The Rtings.com: Chroma Subsampling page has a lot of great detail on what is going on. Specifically this image shows the kind of downsampling happening, and slightly below that they have a couple of images demonstrating the deleterious effect it has on text, particularly text on bright coloured backgrounds.


Artifacts from chroma subsampling are at their most noticeable with text atop a flat color. The impact is far less visible in videos and photos. This matters when connecting your TV to a computer, as you don't want your text to be blurry to the point of being unreadable.

From later on in that page:




This answer is great, but it doesn't explain one thing: how do you change to YCbCr444? Does it depend on the monitor/TV, on the video card, on the video card's driver, on the OS, on the port (HDMI vs DisplayPort), on the cable (can you buy a more expensive one that has higher bandwidth?), on something else?

@FabiosaysReinstateMonica The answer from OP goes some way towards that. It is generally an option in your computer display options where you can configure what mode your computer sends data to the monitor in. This answer focuses more on why, as OP already answered their question of how to fix it.

@FabiosaysReinstateMonica Blame the OP, because there is no question in the "question" (sigh…). As a guess "why?" (answered here) is as good as "how to fix?".

The other two answers are probably better fixes, but one thing you may want to check is if your TV has "Game Mode", "Filmmaker Mode" or "Creator Mode", or other modes you can switch to. I had a Sony TV, that displayed a lot of this 'smearing' but RTings reviewed my exact TV and recommended game mode.
It mostly fixed my problem. The other two answers may fix it even more, but the game mode made a significant difference.
For me, I use 100% scaling at 4k and I'm willing to live with 30fps.
When I game, I use a different monitor (AORUS) that has DispalyPort, and a higher native framerate. Ironically this monitor showed a lot of the same problems, and "Green Mode" is the only thing that fixed THAT problem. I'm going to go back and check the RGB mode now for a hat trick.
Also, your Intel graphics may not be 'real' HDMI 2.1, I and I'd check the TV and see if it's HDMI 2.0 or 2.1. That might explain why the 3070ti card looks better.
My Sony was a 43" TV, at a time when a 42" 4K monitor was extremely expensive. I liked my 4K at 100% scaling enough that I was able to put up with a little chromatic aberration.
Edit: Added the suggestions from Jörg

Some newer TVs have might have a "Filmmaker Mode" or "Creator Mode", which is a sort-of industry standard created by the UHD Alliance which is supposed to mean "display the picture as the artist intended it, don't pretend you know better than the director of the movie what the movies is supposed to look like", i.e., turn off any picture processing. However, manufacturers are not really consistent in how they implement this.

Thanks @JörgWMittag. My TV was a bit older (by now), but that's good to know when/if I shop again.

For future readers who may have other issues with how text is (badly) displayed...
Another setting I stumbled upon which can result in awful quality text was on a Philips T-Line display, where the "Sharpness" is set to 10 by default and results in awful text with shadows and weird colours.
Set it to 0 and the text suddenly becomes crisp and as intended!
